# Does my Sago Palm have root rot?

Tags: trees, roots, palm

My Sago Palm ([Cycas Revoluta](http://www.rhapisgardens.com/sagos/)) has weird-looking clumps in its roots. Is it a [Phytophthora](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=542) root rot infection? If not, what is it?

[image: Root of a Sago Palm]

Answer (score 12):

No, it is not. Those are nitrogen fixation nodules, similar to what alfalfa roots do. It is the result of symbiosis with a soil bacterium.

With root rot the roots die and things get a little stinky. Pinch an affected root with a thumb and forefinger and tug - the epidermal tissues will slide right off the xylem or woody core.

Answer (score 7):

Agree with Jim Young's answer, point given, but would add these are referred to as coralloid roots, and are common on Sago palm, image below

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cycas_revoluta_coralloid_roots.JPG