# What are these seeds I found in the soil of my Windmill Palm?

Tags: identification, seeds

I recently purchased a small Windmill palm from my local Wilkos. It was severely pot bound and I was repotting it when I discovered all these strange seeds in the soil. At first I was hoping they were palm seeds but they don't look like the pictures I've seen. They are about 5 - 10mm (approximately a quarter of an inch) in size. They are hard and the texture is similar to a hazlenut. I'm just curious really as to why they are there and what they could be. Do you think I have any chance of germinating them?

[image][image]

Comment: Were these loose in the potting soil, not actually attached to the roots of the plant?

Comment: Hard to say as the roots were so pot bound there was barely any soil left. It was all just a big tangle. I guess they could have been attached

Comment: I'm wondering if they were root nodules of some sort, although so far as I'm aware, Trachycarpus doesn't have nodules on its roots, but I'm not sure. If they're root nodules, they won't grow, but you could just pot them all up and see if anything happens.

Comment: Sago palm has root nodules for nitrogen fixation: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/23668/does-my-sago-palm-have-root-rot so that's at least a real possibility with a windmill palm, though I don't see a ref to the windmill fixing N2 online. Doesn't look like the nodules turn red when split, from leghemoglobin. That's a strike against nitrogen fixation here.